# C++: divide a loop into several threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

First at all I'm a complete beginner in C++, that's why I apologize if this question may be stupid (or may not have any sense) but I have absolutely no clues about what can I do in my situation.

So, I've been trying to learn about multi-threading lately because I thought it'd be a way much better to use threads instead of a simple loop running across a whole big content (which is the content of a file) to gain actually more speed.

Here's the code I actually have (not complete but it doesn't matters in this case):

```cpp
int end = 40000;
std::string content; // this variable is filled before calling the function "another_function", don't mind it

// this function is completely useless, this is just for testing purposes
void dummy_function(int *idx, int value_to_divide) {
    std::list<int> test;

    for (; *idx <= ending / div; *idx++) {
        int count = 100 + *i;
        test.insert(test.end(), { 1, 2, 3, count });
        std::cout << content.c_str() + *i << endl;
        test.clear();
    }
}

void another_function() {
    int idx = 0;

    std::vector<std::thread> th;

    for (int j = 4; j != 0; j--) {
        th.push_back(std::thread(&dummy_function, &idx + ((j != 4) ? (end / (j + 1)) : 0), j));
    }

    for (auto& thread:th)
        thread.join();
}
```

How I see what I did is that I divide the reading of the content variable into 4 several threads (to make them stopping at the same time as they should have the same length), the first one starting at 0 (beginning), the 2nd one is starting at (i + (end / 3)),
et cetera...

But, it does segfault when the 1st thread stop and in fact the other threads are not even starting where I thought they would start, so maybe I didn't even understand the concept of threading in first place (as I said I'm a beginner in this lol).

I've heard about something called "Safe Queue" or "Safe Threading" (using mutex and stuff related to) but it seems that I didn't understand how to use it in my case.

Is someone able to explain how I could make these threads running in parallel and "safely" (so)?

Thank you :)

Comment: There is book "C++ Concurrency in Action"

Comment: If you are a beginner at C++, then first learn more C++ before diving into threads, at least learn about : std::thread, std::async, std::mutex, std::scoped_lock, std::condition_variable, lambda functions and their captures. And know that threads come with a price too, just throwing n threads at a problem will not make it go n times faster and complexity of your code goes up. Look at cppreference for more information on the classes I mentioned. (In the end you also just need to build up experience)

Comment: If you're really a complete beginner you probably shouldn't be writing code with multiple threads; they can be tricky. Get the basics down first, then take on more complex stuff.

Comment: well, I believe in practice is better than doing nothing because I have to start somewhere, but yes all of you are right (even if I'll learn everything Pepijin talked about, I at leasted wanted to know why it did segfault lol)

Comment: I think whatever the problem is here, it's not to do with threads. Do you get the same segfault if you just call the dummy_function 4 times with those arguments?

Comment: calling the dummy_function with these args does work fine, the moment I try to use threads it segfault

Comment: What's `i` inside `dummy_function`, where does it come from?

Comment: It causes a segfault certainly because of the ugly line `&idx + ((j != 4) ? (end / (j + 1)) : 0)`. I do not know what you wanted to to with that but this result in a bad pointer so dereferencing it later cause an undefined behaviour which can be a segfault in practice. Try to write a code without threads first because this problem is not due to threads. Besides, note that linked lists are generally slow so trying to use multiple thread to speed such a code is certainly not the best option: consider optimizing the sequential code first (especially for an IO-based code).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a threading problem. It's far more basic than that.

Here's your code:

```
void another_function() {
    int idx = 0;

    std::vector<std::thread> th;

    for (int j = 4; j != 0; j--) {
        th.push_back(std::thread(&dummy_function, &idx + ((j != 4) ? (end / (j + 1)) : 0), j));
    }

    for (auto& thread:th)
        thread.join();
}
```

idx is a single integer on the stack. You're passing the address of idx plus some offset that you're calculating. And then your function assumes that's a good address.

But it's NOT a good address. It points out to who knows what. You don't have 40000 integers allocated anywhere. You have exactly 1.

Now, I'm not sure what else you're trying to do, but you could change idx slightly:

```
     int idx[40000];
```

And then I wouldn't do the for-loop quite the same. Instead:

```
    for (int j = 4; j != 0; j--) {
        int offset = j != 4 ? end / (j + 1) : 0;
        th.push_back(std::thread(&dummy_function, &idx[offset], j));
    }
```

Or something like that. I don't think the method you're calling is going to be happy, though, and you would do better to instead pass in the entire array and then a start + length or start + stop values.

But your main problem is because you're running rampant over random memory.